# winjs/javascript: input number validation?

Tags: javascript, validation, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have `textbox` with id `number`. I have 454 `html files` and I displayed these files by the respective input number. if users gives `3` and it will displays `/def/f3.html` and `4` means it will displays `/def/f4.html` and likewise it will all 454 files.

If users gives other than these number, an alert box alerts user. Still now, there is no problem.

What i am asking is, if users gives `003` and it will try to display `/def/f003.html`. Since, i don't have files with that name. it shows error.

Any help regarding this issue, will be seriously much appreciated. JavaScript Code:

```
function buttonClick() 
{
   var getFile = document.getElementById("number").value;
   if (getFile < 455 && getFile > 0) {
      var output = new WinJS.UI.HtmlControl(document.getElementById("def-content"), { uri: '/def/f' + getFile + '.html' });
   } else {
      var popup = Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Expected Value Range: 1 to 454.");
      popup.showAsync();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `var getFile = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value)` and you also have to make sure than no file name number starts with zero except for `f0.html`.

Comment: well. i thought this could be ans. anyways thanks you so much